# Extract the confidence intervals of lmer random effects; plotted with dotplot(ranef())

Tags: r, plot, lme4, confidence-interval

I´m trying to extract the confidence intervals and the intercept values that are plotted with `dotplot(ranef())`. How can I do this?

```
attach(sleepstudy)
library(lme4)
fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), sleepstudy)
lattice::dotplot(ranef(fm1, condVar=TRUE))
```

[image]

I tried exploring the list object `fm1` but could not fiund the CI.

Comment: `attach()` is unnecessary here (and considered harmful)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```r
rr <- ranef(fm1)  ## condVar = TRUE has been the default for a while
```

With `as.data.frame`: gives the conditional mode and SD, from which you can calculate the intervals (technically, these are not "confidence intervals" because the values of the BLUPs/conditional modes are not parameters ...)

```r
dd <- as.data.frame(rr)
transform(dd, lwr = condval - 1.96*condsd, upr = condval + 1.96*condsd)
```

Or with `broom.mixed::tidy`:

```r
broom.mixed::tidy(m1, effects = "ran_vals", conf.int = TRUE)
```

`broom.mixed::tidy()` uses `as.data.frame.ranef.mer()` (the method called by `as.data.frame`) internally: this function takes the rather complicated data structure described in `?lme4::ranef` and extracts the conditional modes and standard deviations in a more user-friendly format:

> If ‘condVar’ is ‘TRUE’ the ‘"postVar"’
> attribute is an array of dimension j by j by k (or a list of such
> arrays).  The kth face of this array is a positive definite
> symmetric j by j matrix.  If there is only one grouping factor in
> the model the variance-covariance matrix for the entire random
> effects vector, conditional on the estimates of the model
> parameters and on the data, will be block diagonal; this j by j
> matrix is the kth diagonal block.  With multiple grouping factors
> the faces of the ‘"postVar"’ attributes are still the diagonal
> blocks of this conditional variance-covariance matrix but the
> matrix itself is no longer block diagonal.

In this particular case, here's what you need to do to replicate the `condsd` column of `as.data.frame()`:

```r
## get the 'postVar' attribute of the first (and only) RE term
aa <- attr(rr$Subject, "postVar")
## for each slice of the array, extract the diagonal;
##  transpose and drop dimensions;
##  take the square root
sqrt(c(t(apply(aa, 3, diag))))
```

Comment: Would you mind to elaborate briefly on what `as.data.frame.ranef.mer` does to get the conditional SD from the `attr(rr$Subject, 'postVar')` (supposedly)?

Comment: Thanks! that is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @jay.sf: does that help?

Comment: @BenBolker Yes thanks, great answer +1